Problem using groupby and transform with conditional lambda on multiple columns in Pandas
I'm curious about a weird behavior I got while using Pandas.
My intial purpose was, for each group in my data, to replace all values in a column with NA when said column contains more than x% missing values and to keep the original values otherwise, NA included.
To do so I've tried using groupby and transform with a lambda containing a conditional statement on x.isna().mean(). It works for the most part but gives weird results when some specific conditions are met.
Here's a reproducible example with a toy dataframe ; the threshold is set to 60% missing values :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "A" : [np.nan, 4.7, 6.6, np.nan, np.nan, 5.4, 6., 5.3],
    "B" : [np.nan, np.nan, 7.2, 15., np.nan, 5.5, np.nan, np.nan],
    "C" : ["D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F"]
    }
 )

df.groupby("C").transform(lambda x : x if x.isna().mean() < .6 else np.nan)

The inital data :
     A     B  C
0  NaN   NaN  D
1  4.7   NaN  D
2  6.6   7.2  D
3  NaN  15.0  E
4  NaN   NaN  E
5  5.4   5.5  F
6  6.0   NaN  F
7  5.3   NaN  F

What I expect :
     A     B
0  NaN   NaN
1  4.7   NaN
2  6.6   NaN
3  NaN  15.0
4  NaN   NaN
5  5.4   NaN
6  6.0   NaN
7  5.3   NaN

What I get :
     A                                       B
0  NaN                                     NaN
1  4.7                                     NaN
2  6.6                                     NaN
3  NaN    3 15.0 4 NaN Name: B, dtype: float64
4  NaN    3 15.0 4 NaN Name: B, dtype: float64
5  5.4                                     NaN
6  6.0                                     Nan
7  5.3                                     NaN

My problem lies in rows 3 and 4 where the entire series is returned instead of the atomic values.
After a few tests, it seems to happen when two conditions are met :

the grouped values in the first column are set to NaN ;
the values in the second column are supposed to stay the same.

If I switch to x.notna() in my condition, the same problem happens when column A contains only valid values and the error always appears in the following columns.
I understand there are other ways to get the wanted result in Pandas so feel free to make suggestions but I'd really like to understand what is happening here : is my code faulty in some way, can it be easily corrected or is it some kind of bug ?
Thanks for your help and sorry if my English is a bit clunky :)
EDIT : I corrected the inconsistency between toy data given in code and the initial data

This looks like a bug, it doesn't happen when you apply the transformations independently:
g = df.groupby('C')
for col in ['A', 'B']:
    print(col)
    print(g[col].transform(lambda x : x if x.isna().mean() < .6 else np.nan))

A
0    NaN
1    4.7
2    6.6
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    5.4
6    6.0
7    5.3
Name: A, dtype: float64
B
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    15.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     NaN
7     NaN
Name: B, dtype: float64

You should report it
In the meantime, you can avoid it by setting the correct number of NaNs as output:
df.groupby('C').transform(lambda x : x if x.isna().mean() < .6
                          else [np.nan]*len(x))


Output:
     A     B
0  NaN   NaN
1  4.7   NaN
2  6.6   NaN
3  NaN  15.0
4  NaN   NaN
5  5.4   NaN
6  6.0   NaN
7  5.3   NaN


Thanks a lot, your test on individual columns seems to confirm my suspicions, I'll consider reporting the potential bug. I also appreciate your solution, groupby's transform is supposed to broadcast scalar values but maybe my issue comes from the different lengths of the candidate outputs of my lambda function.

Indeed, the fact that it behaves differently on multiple columns and individual ones should not happen IMO. Let me know if you report the bug.

Because working with Series you can create mask and set missing values in DataFrame.where with filter only necessary columns:
m = df.groupby("C").transform(lambda x : x.isna().mean()) < .6

#alternative
m = df.isna().groupby(df["C"]).transform('mean') < .6

df[m.columns] = df[m.columns].where(m)
print (df)
     A     B  C
0  NaN   NaN  D
1  4.7   NaN  D
2  6.6   NaN  D
3  NaN  15.0  E
4  NaN   NaN  E
5  5.4   NaN  F
6  6.0   NaN  F
7  5.3   NaN  F


A simple and elegant alternative solution to my problem, many thanks

The biggest issue is that the function passed to the DataFrameGroupBy.transform is expected to receive as an argument the DataFrame containing the group and is expected to return a transformed DataFrame with the same index. This differs from the DataFrame.transform method. For more info check out their docs.
The second issue is that since DataFrameGroupBy.transform actually works on DataFrames and not on pd.Series objects, then x.isna().mean() will actually calculate the percentage of NANs in the whole group across all columns. See DataFrame.mean for more info.
My advice is to create a function that transforms the DataFrame in the way you need to transform a group and simply pass that function to the transform.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [np.nan, 4.7, 6.6, np.nan, np.nan, 5.4, 6.0, 5.3],
        "B": [np.nan, np.nan, 7.2, 15.0, np.nan, 5.5, np.nan, np.nan],
        "C": ["D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F"],
    }
)

def groupby_transform(sub_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    def process_column(series: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
        percent_nan = series.isna().mean()
        if percent_nan < 0.6:
            return series
        else:
            return pd.Series(np.nan, index=series.index, dtype=series.dtype)

    return sub_df.transform(process_column, axis=0)

df.groupby("C").transform(groupby_transform)

This outputs
     A     B
0  NaN   NaN
1  4.7   NaN
2  6.6   NaN
3  NaN  15.0
4  NaN   NaN
5  5.4   NaN
6  6.0   NaN
7  5.3   NaN


This is partially true, df.groupby('C')['B'].transform(lambda x : x if x.isna().mean() < .6 else np.nan) gives OP's expected output. The inconsistency/bug lies in the fact that several columns are processed together. See my answer for a demonstration.

From what I see the DataFrame initialized in code  and the one shown in Initial data section differ, so the code from my answer does what his initial goal was.

"DataFrameGroupBy.transform actually works on DataFrames" -> this is also incorrect. DataFrameGroupBy.transform definitely works per column, independently (which is why the reported behavior is buggy). DataFrameGroupBy.apply would work on the whole DataFrame.

Thanks for your answer, I'll check your adviced solution soon. I'm in no place to tell which one of you is right but regarding the second problem, it appears to me that df.groupby("C").transform(lambda x : x.isna().mean()) returns the NA percentage for each group and each column, not across all columns

@TimDdckr the proposed solution is this answer is correct (It's actually similar to what I had suggested in mine), but there are a lot of incorrect statements on the reasons and the behavior of groupby.

I agree that the pandas implementation is inconsistent and buggy, but from what I gather from the docs, it does what it says. I agree that it should work the same as when calling transform on the DataFrame directly. I downwoted your answer because it didn't explain how to implement the desired behaviour, it just showcased what happens when you do it in a for-loop. My answer does a similar thing actually, which is actually transforming each group separately, with the added benefit of joining the results back together in a single DataFrame.

@Grinjero I guess you missed the "In the meantime, you can avoid it by setting the correct number of NaNs as output:" with relevant code from my answer. It does provide a functional solution to avoid triggering the bug… and is actually based on the same principle that you suggested in yours (using a list instead of a Series) after I had answered.

Fair enough, seem to have missed it
